# Can a case be created even when I receive SQL timeout expired from Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, xrm

I am calling Microsoft CRM Dynamics 2011's Web service & I am getting SQL timeout expired from the CRM?

My Question is can I get SQL timeout expired & still case be created in CRM?

Thanks,
Kind Regards,
Umang Parikh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, it could possibly happen but there is no guarantee that it will happen. It would depend on when CRM is throwing the timeout - which you would need to do tracing to determine. If it is after the create transaction has completed then it wouldn't rollback the create.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the quick response.  So you're saying that the SQL Timeout is not necessarily from Create command. it could be after create command has been executed successfully & some other plugin runs on the case which causes the issue?

Comment: Correct, all you know is that during a SQL command that there was timeout. You have to turn on CRM tracing and work through the logs (and/or use SQL Profiler) to find the specific statement causing the timeout. It probably isn't a plugin because synchronous post-create plugins should run in the transaction - but I can't guarantee it. If you edit your question with a full description of what is happening we'll probably be able to better help you.

Comment: Hey, I unfortunately do not much details of what is going in CRM. I make a web service call to CRM to create a case & I expect GUID back but I receive an error . For my point of view it is a complete failure and hence I retry case creation which causes duplicate cases creation. But I think you have helped & thanks for clarifying :)